# How to get PowerShell to loop Get-Content properly with -Tail

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get PowerShell to keep reading lines of a file, specifically the tail, and it will call a function for each line.

```
foreach ($log in Get-Content pathtofilehere -Tail 0 -Wait) { ... }
```

but this method does not seem to be working, was wondering if anyone has any suggestions?

Comment: Use pipeline: `Get-Content pathtofilehere -Tail 0 -Wait | % { ... }`

Comment: Get-Content pathtofilehere -Tail 0 -Wait | % { SendTo-LogEntries "secrettoken" $_ }  is what I found after looking at pipeline percent.

Comment: And it is working perfectly, looks like the provider switched the token, but the powershell is now running!